# Additional sobolev regularity from laplace

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Given a bounded Lipschitz domain $U\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and a function $u\in W^{2,2}(U)$ with $\Delta u\in L^p(U)$ for some $p>2$, does $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$ hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, at least for $\,p=6\,$. This is according to the [Sobolev Embedding Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Sobolev_embedding_theorem) which states

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
k>l \\ 1\le q<p<\infty \\ \big(k-l\big)\,q<n \\ \dfrac{1}{p} = \dfrac{1}{q} - \dfrac{k-l}{n}
\end{cases}
\implies W^{k,q}\big(\mathbb R^n\big) \subseteq W^{l,p}\big(\mathbb R^n\big)
\end{align}

In your case $\, n=3,\, k=2,\, l = 1,\, q = 2,\,$ and thus $\,p=6$.

Comment: Thanks, I already got that far and thought it didn't help for $p>6$, but I just realized that this and further Sobolev embeddings seem to be enough for a bootstrapping argument if I assume certain boundary conditions for my $u$.